# Runtime error: When accessing a Reader in struct

Tags: go

I'm new to go and trying to implement an interface for video operations (download, upload, transcode). In my download method I'm creating a Reader and assigning it to struct variable 'fileContent'. I'd then like to access the Reader in my upload method but it's throwing a runtime error.

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Below is a link to my code in go playground. Any help would be great.

https://play.golang.org/p/ib38IQ6AZI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using non-pointer receiver:

```
func (b BaseVideo) Download() (err error) {
    b.fileContent = bytes.NewReader([]byte("abc"))
    return nil
}
```

This means your `Download()` method gets a *copy* of the `BaseVideo` value you're calling it on. You modify this copy inside the method (you assign a new `Reader` to the `fileContent` field), but the original `BaseVideo` **will not be modified**.

Solution: use a pointer receiver:

```
func (b *BaseVideo) Download() (err error) {
    b.fileContent = bytes.NewReader([]byte("abc"))
    return nil
}
```

Of course if you modify the receiver to be a pointer, the type `BaseVideo` will no longer implement the `Video` interface, only a pointer to `BaseVideo`, so also modify `NewBaseVideo` to return a pointer to the struct value: `*BaseVideo`. You can achieve this by taking the address of the struct literal:

```
func NewBaseVideo(path, name string) Video {
    return &BaseVideo{
        Path: path,
        Name: name,
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mutate the value in a methods, the receiver of the method should be a pointer. Replace

```
func (b BaseVideo) Download() (err error)
```

and such with

```
func (b *BaseVideo) Download() (err error)
```

Working code on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/hZ8-RwzVYh.